# Modify database Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have to do modifications on a website using Laravel which i never used before.

I made this div in the form, in my view file :

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Organisme</label>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    @if(Auth::user()->hasRole(['responsable_rh', 'responsable_formation', 'responsable_qual']))
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="organismeShow" value="{{$orga_user[0]->nom}}" readonly>
      <input type="hidden" name="id_organisme" value="{{$orga_user[0]->id_organisme}}">
    @elseif(Auth::user()->hasRole(['admin', 'super_admin']))
       <select class="form-control chosen" name="id_organisme" autocomplete="off">
       @foreach($all_orga as $val)
         @if($val->id_organisme==13)
           <OPTION selected value="{{$val->id_organisme}}">{{$val->nom}}</OPTION>
         @else
           <OPTION value="{{$val->id_organisme}}">{{$val->nom}}</OPTION>
         @endif
       @endforeach
       </select>
    @endif
   </div>
</div>
```

It works well, I have my list showing up. Now I need to make it change a value in the database but I don't know at all where to modify things. Know that this form already existed in the previous version, and already modify things in database, but I have to add this section.

Form opener :

```
{!!Form::open(array('id'=>'check_form', 'route' => 'rh_ajout_update'))!!} 
{!!Form::close()!!}
{!!Form::open(array('class'=>'form-horizontal', 'route'=>'update_user', 'files' => 'true', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'))!!}
{!!Form::hidden('id_compte', $compte->id_compte)!!}
```

Comment: When you say "modify database", do you mean that the form should update a record in the database? Tried the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2?

Comment: Yes, sorry for poor practical English. I need it to update _Organisme_ in the database, i just don't know where to put this modification.

Comment: Your question is impossible for us to answer without the full code base since Laravel allows you to do the same task in many different ways. You should read up on how Laravel is structured, then you can try to find it yourself.